# How this "voice dialer" shows up?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, voice-command

Sometimes I'm listening to music on my phone (running Android KitKat), and from my pocket the phone make a sound and the first screenshot shows up and then the second one appears:

[image]
[image]

<sup>Click image(s) for larger version</sup>

What makes this shows up and how can I stop it?

Comment: Are you accidentally activating the voice dialer by your pocket movements? The same way you can pocket dial by mistake.

Comment: @Huey yes, but I don't know how this is activated... is it a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Now assistant can be activated by long-pressing the button of the earphone, looks like you use the buttons to control music, but is pressing it too long.

Another thing that could be, are you using original earphones? Some earphones, because of incompatibility, keep sending commands even though you are not pressing buttons. Use another earphone for a day and see it the problem occurs, if it doesn't, the problem is in the earphone.

Comment: Yes, I do think it's something with the earphones... If I simply move the earphones sometimes it will crash/close my player app also.